# Processing lines of a file with various space-separated fields of strings, hex addresses, and integer addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have a plain text file which contains lines with fields below:

```
<str_addr_a> <hex_int_addr>
<str_addr_a> <hex_int_addr> <dec_int_addr>
<str_addr_a> <str_addr_b>
<str_addr_a> <str_addr_b> <hex_int_addr>
<str_addr_a> <str_addr_b> <hex_int_addr> <dec_int_addr>
```

For example, the content of the file could be following:

```
# <str_addr_a> <hex_int_addr>
dkfi A18A

# <str_addr_a> <str_addr_b>
kloe uuep

# <str_addr_a> <str_addr_b> <hex_int_addr> <dec_int_addr>
ctff yaaq BBF2 19

# <str_addr_a> <str_addr_b> <hex_int_addr>
fkii hhyf E118

# <str_addr_a> <str_addr_b> <hex_int_addr> <dec_int_addr>
ctkj yuuq BBF0 12
```

I'm reading the file with function below:

```
def read_data(file):
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:

        addresses = []

        for line_nr, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            line = line.strip()
            if line and not line.startswith('#'):

                str_addr_a = str_addr_b = hex_int_addr = dec_int_addr = None

                try:
                    # '<str_addr_a> <hex_int_addr>'
                    str_addr_a, hex_int_addr = line.split()

                    if not is_valid_str_addr(str_addr_a):
                        raise ValueError from None
                    hex_int_addr = hex_addr(hex_int_addr).compress

                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        # '<str_addr_a> <hex_int_addr> <dec_int_addr>'
                        str_addr_a = hex_int_addr = None
                        str_addr_a, hex_int_addr, dec_int_addr = line.split()

                        if not is_valid_str_addr(str_addr_a):
                            raise ValueError from None
                        hex_int_addr = hex_addr(hex_int_addr).compress
                        dec_int_addr = int(dec_int_addr)

                    except ValueError:
                        try:
                            # '<str_addr_a> <str_addr_b>'
                            str_addr_a = hex_int_addr = dec_int_addr = None
                            str_addr_a, str_addr_b = line.split()

                            if not is_valid_str_addr(str_addr_a):
                                raise ValueError from None

                            if not is_valid_str_addr(str_addr_b):
                                raise ValueError from None

                        except ValueError:
                            try:
                                # '<str_addr_a> <str_addr_b> <hex_int_addr>'
                                str_addr_a = str_addr_b = None
                                str_addr_a, str_addr_b, hex_int_addr = line.split()

                                if not is_valid_str_addr(str_addr_a):
                                    raise ValueError from None

                                if not is_valid_str_addr(str_addr_b):
                                    raise ValueError from None

                                hex_int_addr = hex_addr(hex_int_addr).compress

                            except ValueError:
                                try:
                                    # '<str_addr_a> <str_addr_b> <hex_int_addr>
                                    # <dec_int_addr>'
                                    str_addr_a = str_addr_b = hex_int_addr = None
                                    str_addr_a, str_addr_b, hex_int_addr, \
                                    dec_int_addr = line.split()

                                    if not is_valid_str_addr(str_addr_a):
                                        raise ValueError from None

                                    if not is_valid_str_addr(str_addr_b):
                                        raise ValueError from None

                                    hex_int_addr = hex_addr(hex_int_addr).compress

                                    dec_int_addr = int(dec_int_addr)

                                except ValueError:
                                    logging.error(f'{file}: error on line number {line_nr}')
                                    continue

                addresses.append((str_addr_a, str_addr_b, hex_int_addr, dec_int_addr))

    return(addresses)
```

As seen above, each `try/except` block tests one of the possible line formats. Such code introduces quite a lot of branches and isn't very flat. Is there a more elegant way to process such data file? Or perhaps the way I'm doing this is fine?

Comment: What does it do?  What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: We also seem to be missing the functions `is_valid_str_addr` and `hex_addr`.

Comment: And what is `hex_addr().compress`?

Comment: Next time, please don't forget to post your imports and class declarations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would benefit from re-interpreting this input as having "only one format", with one mandatory field and three other optional fields. A regex can capture this better than your nested try blocks.

You need to separate individual record line parsing from parsing of the file.

Add unit tests.

### Suggested

File and `#` handling not shown.

```
import re
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional


RECORD_PAT = re.compile(
    r'''(?x)
    ^
    (?P<str_addr_a>
        [a-z]{4}
    )
    (?:
        \s+
        (?P<str_addr_b>
            [a-z]{4}
        )
    )?
    (?:
        \s+
        (?P<hex_int_addr>
            [A-F0-9]{4}
        )
    )?
    (?:
        \s+
        (?P<dec_int_addr>
            \d+
        )
    )?
    $
    '''
)


class Record(NamedTuple):
    str_addr_a: str
    str_addr_b: Optional[str]
    hex_int_addr: Optional[str]
    dec_int_addr: Optional[int]

    @classmethod
    def from_line(cls, line: str) -> 'Record':
        *first, dec_int_addr = RECORD_PAT.match(line).groups()
        if dec_int_addr is not None:
            dec_int_addr = int(dec_int_addr)
        return cls(*first, dec_int_addr)


def test() -> None:
    r = Record.from_line('dkfi A18A')
    assert r.str_addr_a == 'dkfi'
    assert r.str_addr_b is None
    assert r.hex_int_addr == 'A18A'
    assert r.dec_int_addr is None

    r = Record.from_line('kloe uuep')
    assert r.str_addr_a == 'kloe'
    assert r.str_addr_b == 'uuep'
    assert r.hex_int_addr is None
    assert r.dec_int_addr is None

    r = Record.from_line('ctff yaaq BBF2 19')
    assert r.str_addr_a == 'ctff'
    assert r.str_addr_b == 'yaaq'
    assert r.hex_int_addr == 'BBF2'
    assert r.dec_int_addr == 19

    r = Record.from_line('fkii hhyf E118')
    assert r.str_addr_a == 'fkii'
    assert r.str_addr_b == 'hhyf'
    assert r.hex_int_addr == 'E118'
    assert r.dec_int_addr is None

    r = Record.from_line('ctkj yuuq BBF0 12')
    assert r.str_addr_a == 'ctkj'
    assert r.str_addr_b == 'yuuq'
    assert r.hex_int_addr == 'BBF0'
    assert r.dec_int_addr == 12


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: It looks like a `dec_int_addr` can only be present if there is a `hex_int_addr`. This could be included in the regex pattern by nesting the `dec_int_addr` pattern inside the `hex_int_addr` pattern.